# Transferring string from one node.js instance to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, transfer

I will try to be as clear and concise as possible here, I hope this isn't too abstract for anyone to understand.

I have two node.js instances running, one acting as a server, while the other is acting as a client.

Instance 1, the server is hosted in a datacenter, this server upon each request generates a text based certificate and Instance 2, the client gets the certificate and verifies that the server is who it really says it is.

Using the module prompt, the client asks the user in the console for a key, the issue is I have no idea how to transfer said key as a string back to instance 1, the server.

Might there be any way to accomplish this?

The basic underlying question here, is how can a string be transferred from one instance to another?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create one common app.js which will run two separate node instances using cluster. After it you can share any values between clusters.

2) Writing string to a socket/file

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use an HTTP POST request for something like this. It sounds like a very basic API.